# Reference request for semilinear PDEs in dimension 2

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I am interested in the study of the (semi-linear, I suppose) equation
$$\begin{cases}-\Delta u(x,y)+q(x)u(x,y)+h(x)=f(u(x,y)-kx),\;\;(x,y)\in\Omega,\\
u=g,\;\;\;\text{on }\partial\Omega.\end{cases}$$
on an open bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with piecewise $C^1$ boundary. Here $k\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant, and $f$ is a continuous non-linearity that is strictly greater than linear growth, i.e., $|f(x)|\geq |a|+b|x|^\gamma$ with $\gamma> 1$.

> **Question.** What are known results about such equations? Is there a reference for them?

It would be highly appreciated if the answer contains a brief discussion on the results in the literature if possible, although I'd be satisfied with just the references.

**Added.** I am mainly interested in existence results for the weak formulation of the equation. As for boundary conditions, we could take Dirichlet for simplicity but I would be interested in more generality.

Comment: $x\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $h,q$ are functions of one variable only. I'll edit the question.

Comment: This covers so, so many equations, even when $h = 0 = q$ and $k = 0$. You'll get a much better answer if you explain what sort of results you're after.

Comment: @LeoMoos Let's say for simplicity that $q\equiv 1$ and and $h$ is linear, and definitely $k\neq 0$. This is good enough for now, but I would like relax these assumptions to $h,q\in L^\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are in dimension $2$, which is nice, because $H^{1}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^N(\Omega)$ for any $N<\infty$ so you can look for a normal, weak solution.  The other good news is that behind your problem is a compact operator.

Let us assume $q\in L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$, $q\geq0$, $g\in H^{1/2}\left(\partial\Omega\right),$
$h\in L^{N}\left(\Omega\right)$, and
$$
\left|f\left(x\right)\right|\leq N+\left|x\right|^{N},
$$
for some $N>1.$  Then, the operator
\begin{align*}
T_q: H^{-1}(\Omega) \to &H^1_0(\Omega) \\ 
\ell \to & u \text{ the solution of } \\
&-\Delta u + q u = \ell
\end{align*}
is well defined and continuous, thanks to Lax--Milgram (this is where $q\geq0$ is useful) and Sobolev
embeddings (in dimension $2$, $L^N(\Omega)\hookrightarrow H^{-1}(\Omega)$).

Let $u_{0}\in H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$ be the weak
solution of
\begin{align*}
-\Delta u_{0}+qu_{0}+h & =0\text{ in }\Omega,\\
u_{0} & =g\text{ on }\partial\Omega.
\end{align*}

Writing $\kappa:x\to kx$ your problem writes

\begin{align*}
-\Delta\left(u-u_{0}\right) & +q\left(u-u_{0}\right)=f\left(u - \kappa\right)\text{ in }\Omega\\
u-u_{0} & =0\text{ on }\partial\Omega.
\end{align*}

In other words,
\begin{align*}
u -u_0 &= T_q f\left(u-u_0+u_0-\kappa\right)\\
u -u_0 &= K(u-u_0) \\
&\text{with }  K:=a\to T_q  f(a +u_0- \kappa)
\end{align*}
Now $K: H^1_0\to H^1_0$ is a compact operator, as a composition of compact and continuous operators:

- The continuous map in $H^1(\Omega)$ $a\to a+ u_0-\kappa$,
- The compact embedding
  $
  H^1_0(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^{2N}(\Omega),
  $
- The continuous map $f:L^{2N}(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$
- The compact embedding $L^{2}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow H^{-1}(\Omega)$
- The continuous map $T_q: H^{-1}(\Omega) \to  H^1_0(\Omega)$.

So $u-u_0$ is a fixed point of $K$...[Schauder's Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed-point_theorem) comes to mind. Alternatively, because you have positive operators and a maximum principle you can probably get away with a constructive method of iterating sub/super solutions as decribed in Evan's PDE book.

Lecture notes detailing both points of view are [here](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/2037), and many references are included.

Comment: Thank you for the details on Schauder fixed point theorem and the notes. Could you just outline the constructive method? If not can you at least pinpoint exactly where it is in the Evans book/ notes you linked?

Comment: Pages 31 to 37 in the notes for both, and Chapter "non variational methods" in Evans (monotonicity etc.).

Comment: The constructive method of Theorem 32 in the notes you provided (which are great by the way!) assume that $f$ is sub-linear. Do you think there is a similar method for sub-quadratic?

Comment: And one last thing, where did you use that $f$ has bounded growth rate? Is it to guaranteeing that $T_q^{-1}(\cdot-\kappa)+\zeta$ is compact?

Comment: @UserA The growth rate is so that  $f(u)$ is in some $L^N$... Sublinear is not so important. Try, with your $f$, to see if the steps work. But Schauder seems like a shoe in for this case. If you read the next chapter, you can try also the monotone operator approach, it would probably work beautifully too if $f$ is monotone.

Comment: How do you justify the claim that there is a maximum principle when no sign is specified for $q$ in the question? Without this, the operator $T_q$ seems ill-defined.

Comment: @LeoMoos The OP suggested to choose $q\equiv1$ in the comments so I inferred he was considering a positive $q$. I have added this to the post. In fact I had written it, but somehow it had disappeared, some typing error on my part.

Comment: @username how do you reformulate the problem in $H^1_0$?

Comment: @username by solving the linear part you mean setting the non-linear part to 0? How does that work?

Comment: @UserA All details explicitely written now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer.

Comment: @username If $|f(u)|\leq N+|u|^N$ then we can show that $|f(u)|^p\leq 2^p N^p+|x|^{Np}$ for all $p$.  But this does not mean that $f(u)\in L^N$ as you claimed in the previous comment. Now I know we are looking for $u\in H^1_0\subset L^2$, and thus we want $Np\leq 2$ ie $p=2/N$. But the only way to get $p\geq 1$ is that $N\leq 2$. So this argument works only for $N\leq 2$ I guess?

Comment: @userA : if $u\in L^{Np}$ then $f(u)\in L^p$. Luckily if $u\in H^1$ in dimension two then $u\in L^{Np}$ for any $N>1$ and $p>1$ not infinity. the "N" in the previous comment means "some N not infinity". You use $H^1_0\hookrightarrow L^{Np}$, not $L^2$.

Comment: @username one question: is the map $T_q:H^{-1}(\Omega)\to H^1_0(\Omega)$ compact?

Comment: @UserA No, it is not compact. But if you compose continuous maps and compact maps, the compound is compact.